# To concatenate values of a particular column in multiple rows using linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table in sql server with the following structure.

tblFruit:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  Fruit       ║ Color║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Peacock      ║ Red  ║
║  2 ║ Hawk         ║ Green║
║  3 ║ Lion         ║ Red  ║
║  4 ║ Lizard       ║ Red  ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

This is my query in LINQ :

```
db.Fruits.Where(r => r.Color == "Red")
         .Select(r => r.Fruit)
         .ToList()
```

I will get 3 rows of result from the table.

However I need the result to be Peacock,Lion,Lizard. Is there a way of getting this from LINQ or should I use a foreach loop and concatenate manually?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var fruits = db.Fruits.Where(r => r.Color == "Red")
                      .Select(r => r.Fruit)
                      .AsEnumerable();

Console.WriteLine(String.join(",", fruits));
```

Comment: Does String.Join work with Linq to Entities?

Comment: @maccettura Sorry, javascript is starting to slowly consume my soul

Comment: No. In EF6 this will be translated into SQL and `string.Join` is not supported. You have to use `fruits.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @GertArnold exactly what I was trying to say, thanks for the more decent explanation :)

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, you are correct. You will need to involve `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`, or `.AsEnumerable();` before working with the data, to avoid the magic behind the scenes of the `IQueryable` interface.